# $scope.$apply doesn't do anything in a Chrome extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension, angularjs

I'm writing a chrome extension that consists of a background process and a popup.  The background process continually makes ajax requests to get new data, and the popup displays the info.

In an extremely simplified way, the background.js process looks like this:

```
var Background = {
    data: {},
    poll: function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'some_url',
            success: function(data) {
                this.data = data;
                chrome.extension.sendMessage('update');
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    startPolling: function() {
        setInterval(this.poll.bind(this), 10000);
    }
};
$(Background.startPolling.bind(Background));
```

This shoots of an ajax request every 10 seconds, gets some data back, and sets it to `Background.data`.  Again, this is very simplified.  You can see the `sendMessage` call in the success callback.

My popup.js looks something like this, also extremely simplified:

```
var Background = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().Background;

angular.module('App', [])
    .controller('PopupCtrl', function PopupCtrl($scope) {

        $scope.data = Background.data;

        chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if (request == 'update') {
                console.log('update');
                $scope.$apply();
            }
        });

    });
```

And of course, popup.html looks something like:

```
<html ng-app="App" ng-csp>
    <body ng-controller="PopupCtrl">
        <p>{{data.title}}</p>
        <p>{{data.body}}</p>
        <p>{{data.date}}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The message is definitely received, because I can see `"update"` print to the console every 10 second interval.  I also know that the data is being updated properly because if I close and reopen the popup, the new data is displayed correctly.  So `$scope.$apply()` is simply not doing anything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: But in your 'onMessage' listener you're also doing nothing, except logging to console? What's to apply?

Comment: Further up in my code (not shown here), the data object that is part of the scope is a reference to the data that is updated in the background.  I will edit my question so you can see what I mean shortly.

Comment: actually @Stewie, you may be right - `$scope.data` may not actually be getting set properly, and might just be resetting when the javascript re-runs each time the window opens.  Have to look into it a bit more.

Comment: Yeah, `$scope.data = Background.data` did not work because `this.data = data` in the ajax callback was unlinking the reference, instead of updating the one that existed.  I changed and now it works. `$scope.$apply()` was not the problem.  Whoops.

Comment: @cilphex Closing the question would be great then :)

Comment: @Flek - I agree, I tried to, but it looks like I have to vote like everybody else.  So I placed my vote to close and it now has 1 out of 5 necessary votes to close. Help me out and cast a vote to close as well?  Unless there's a way I can override...

Comment: @cilphex Ah okay :) Yeah then we just need to wait. Thanks.