# Change text input value with jQuery - Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to change input value in particular web site from chrome extension. In order to do that I am using jQuery in my content script. It works in most of the cases, but I didn't manage to change value of the input when it is part of AngularJS view. I found the same problem when I use let say kendoUI. I am trying to set the value calling `$('element').val('value')` and then try to call blur and change event, but without any success.
I went through may be 99% of the posts related to this topic, but still can't find working solution.

Comment: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html best article to understand your problem...

Comment: Is that means that my problem does not have a solution?

Comment: no, it is very basic concept but you should know it, when you manipulate dom outside of angular, angular does not know anything about it that is why you cannot see any changes... to solve it you should wrap your jquery function with $scope.apply() then angular get changes...

Comment: But how can I call $scope.apply() outside of angularjs world. How I mentioned I am injecting jQuery code from my content script. Actually I do not inject it but call the eval() method.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to Call $scope.apply() in order to let angular know about updating the bindings. This is mainly because by default, angular doesn't know anything about the changes you are making in jQuery.

Below is a sample code, and here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9F68Y/11/). Hope this helps.

```
app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.changeValue = function() {
     $('#test').val("new Value");
        $scope.apply();
    }

  <div class="form-inline">
            <input type="text" id="test" value="test">
            <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-click="changeValue()">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But probably I didn't explain my problem clear enough. Imagine that you have a web site with one text input in it (you do not have the code and you are not the owner of this site). Form your chrome extension you have  to change the value of this input. In order to do that I am using jQuery.va(). And here is my problem, this approach does not work for case when the MVC pattern is implemented like when the site is developed with angularjs.

Comment: I haven't tried it using a chrome extension, so I'm not sure about it. I found a similar question that you might find it a bit helpful.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595972/scope-apply-doesnt-do-anything-in-a-chrome-extension-popup